# How to delete node from doubly linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on doubly linked list in c, I have a doubly linked tepm2 with 20 nodes and I want to delete the node whose word user insert.

```
struct node {
    struct node *prev;
    char word[100];
    int repeatTime;
    struct node *next;
} *h, *temp, *temp1, *temp2;
```

Each node has unique word.

```
printf("\n Enter word to delete  : ");
scanf("%s", &word);
Delete(word);

int delete(char data[200]) {      //unable to delete
    if (h == NULL)
        return;

    temp2 = next = previous = h;

    while (temp2->next != NULL) {
        if ((strcmp(temp2->word, data) == 0)) {
            if (temp2->prev == NULL) {
                h = temp2->next;
                free(temp2);
                return;
            } else if (temp2->prev == NULL) {
                previous->next = temp2;
                free(temp2);
                previous->next = NULL;
                return;
            } else {
                previous->next = temp2->next;
                next->prev = temp2->next;
            }
        }

        temp2 = temp->next;
    }
}
```

I am been unable to delete the specific node that word user enter

Comment: Why do you test for two identical conditions? `if (temp2->prev == NULL)` and `else if (temp2->prev == NULL)`

Comment: I had copy this delete function, but i cant understand it logic..

Comment: Better throw it away and try to write your own.

Comment: I have write code to delete single linked-list and that works, but I cant understand how to delete node from doubly linked list

Comment: Draw a picture to visualize it. If you know how to delete a node from a singly linked-list, doing so for a doubly linked-list follows plainly. Take the same action you would for a singly linked-list, then deal with the `prev` pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int delete(const char *data)
{
    struct node *temp = h;

    if (h == NULL) return;

    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp->word, data) == 0)
        {
            if (temp->prev != NULL)
            {
                temp->prev->next = temp->next;
            }
            if (temp->next != NULL)
            {
                temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
            }
            if (h == temp)
            {
                h = temp->next;
            }
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: @UsfNoor There could be several reasons for that. Perhaps the doubly linked list pointed to by `h` is not validly constructed in the first place, or perhaps the word you are trying to delete is not on the list!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't think this is right `temp2 = next = previous = h;`

Now all you have to do is find the node that you want to delete by traversing and than link it's prev node to it's next node i.e. (temp2->prev)->next = next and (temp2->next)->prev = prev and free it.

Now the real issue lies with 
1. The first node that has other nodes after it
2. last node that has other nodes preceding it
3. only node

You can simplify all three by converting them into the former problem i.e. node in the middle problem which we've just solved.

For simplifying you can just make the head and tail both NULL.